# What can I do to prevent wxDev-C++ stop working when adding a big *.c file to my project?

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

When I try to add a big *.c file to my project it takes too much time parsing the new file. What should I do or can do to prevent it?

added:
I returned to 5.9.2 version of Dev-C++ there is no such problem there.
In future I will try wxDev-C++ again to see if the problem is solved or not.

Comment: Try a different IDE or see if there's a "nightly" version available. (unofficial release, that's more recent than yours - it could have some bug-fixes in it)  Code::Blocks serves me very well.

Comment: Maybe it's not a bug. There should be some option to prevent parsing files when adding to project or opening it.

Comment: Perhaps not. You can always make a suggestion to add such a feature, if one doesn't already exist.Failing that (or at least, before such a feature is available) you can either (a) do something else while the file is parsed or (b) try a different IDE. Using Code::Blocks on an i7 3537u, it takes 12 seconds to load sqlite3.c - this file is 5,158kb and has 148,883 lines